# Cannot upload image in Rails and Appcelerator

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, appcelerator

I am developing an iPhone app in Appcelerator Titanium. My app is communicating with an API that I build using Rails 3.

I want to be able to upload an image from the iPhone app to the API (and Amazon S3). I am using the gem called Paperclip. Along with the upload request I need to send the name of the file. But if I do it like below, the image_file_name is not recognized. What is wrong with the call?

In the App: http://pastie.org/1805065

In the API model: http://pastie.org/1805071

In the API controller: http://pastie.org/1805073

Output on the API server: http://pastie.org/1805078

Comment: These links are dead for me, Pastie seems to be down. This highlights the importance of adding code/input/output into the question itself, rather than on paste boards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like in the API Controller the line:

```
@avatar = Avatar.new(params[:avatar])
```

Should read:

```
@avatar = Avatar.new(params[:image])
```

Explanation:

This conclusions was made by looking at the server log output from the API Server, and checking the Parameters hash for the name of the submitted image. Instead of it being named "avatar" as your controller was expecting, it appears to actually be named "image".

Comment: I did the changes you suggested but I unfortunately get errors. Here is the API server log: http://pastie.org/1805101.

Comment: I think you are on the right track. If I put a ! after @avatar.save I get this clue: http://pastie.org/1805120.

Comment: This is a correct output where I use the almost the same code in a webbased Ruby on Rails app. http://pastie.org/1805171.

Comment: Did you get it to work? That last log entry seems like it's working

Comment: Did you have a solution to this? I am stuck over here > http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5903565/titanium-rails-paperclip-null-values. Thanks for any advice!